# Optimizing Fargate Tasks

Tags: angular, spring-boot, docker, amazon-rds, aws-fargate

I’ve got some complexity when trying to develop a strategy for optimizing the performance of some of my apps on Fargate. While the apps are deployed, there is still some major lag.

So the images are uploaded to ECR and deployed on Fargate. Service discovery is enabled for inter-container communication. Among the containers, there are four spring boot apis that are connecting with various Oracle RDSs and then there are containerized angular apps that are consuming the apis and pulling in all that data via REST calls.

I don’t want to get into the setting jvm heap size or stuff like that. For starters I need to know what would be a ballpark estimate of the standard mem and cpu usage for the UIs and apis. Generally the images in ecr for the UIs are each around 50-60MB and the apis range from 200-260mb.

Insights appreciated as to what to try for the apis and UIs and/or a strategy for making the performance better. I do have container insights enabled but I’ve read that some of those numbers can be misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled container insights on each of the clusters in ecs to track cpu and mem usage and found that they were doing well at the limits I had set which was typically 2vcpu and 4gb. The issue was with the RDS calls which that were causing the lag and the amount of data.